# 2 classes with same Id how to change property and reflect in both

Tags: java, c#

I have 3 classes where each of them may have different property, let us say a class name with pen 
and other class with hand,at present let us take both id's with 1,2,3.. so on.If i have many ids or objects with different ids ,both hand id and pen id is same, 
only hand id 1 can use pen id 1 similarly hand id 2 can use pen id 2 .

```
class Hand{ 
      string Id;
      bool Status;
      Hand(string id){
            Id=1;
            Status=false
      }
}
class Pen{ 
      string Id
      bool Status;
      Pen(string id){
            Id=1;
            Status=false;
      }
}
class Pencil{ 
      string Id
      bool Status;
      Pen(string id){
            Id=1;
            Status=false;
      }
}
```

so if i change Hand.status=true it should automatically get changed in pen.status or pencil with that id should get changed to true.
let us suppose.
hand id 1,2,3 all status are false
pen has id 1,3
pencil has id 2
if hand of id 2 is changed to true that id which is found in pencil with id should change
how to map them or how to establish connection between two classes
Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be work.

```
class Hand
{
    public int Id;
    private bool m_Status;
    public bool Status
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Status;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Status = value;
            if (Pen != null)
            {
                Pen.Status = value;
            }
        }
    }
    Pen Pen { get; set; }

    Hand(int id)
    {
        Id=1;
        Status=false;
    }
}

class Pen
{
    public int Id;
    public bool Status;
    Pen(int id)
    {
        Id=1;
        Status=false;
    }
}
```

*** Added / Modified ***

you can also extend your class like this.

```
class Hand
{
    public int Id;
    private bool m_Status;
    public bool Status
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Status;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Status = value;
            if (Item != null)
            {
                Item.Status = value;
            }
        }
    }
    Item Item { get; set; }

    Hand(int id)
    {
        Id=id;
        Status=false;
    }
}

class Item
{
    public int Id;
    public bool Status;
    public Item(int id)
    {
        Id=id;
        Status=false;
    }
}

class Pen : Item
{
    public Pen(int id)
        : base(id)
    {

    }
}


class Eraser : Item
{
    Eraser(int id)
        : base(id)
    {

    }
}


class Pencil : Item
{
    public Pencil(int id)
        : base(id)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: you can also add hand variable in pen. get hand.Status instead of Pen's Status

Comment: like this. bool Status { get => Hand.Status }

Comment: thanks for helping me out your logic works great but i have n number of classes. where your code works only for pen , I have classes with pen, pencil,eraser etc

Comment: @virus : what's your purpose to doing this?

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for not describing it earlier.

Comment: virus : is this for painter? if you doing this, why don't you use wpf/inkcanvas ? it will be perfectly good for doing this without codes.

Comment: no no its not for painter, i just trying out different thinks , by the way thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if 2 objects are dependent mostly they will have a `HAS-A` or `IS-A` Relationship, can you rethink your design

Ideally if your classes are correctly named you could have a `Hand Has a Pen relationship` (or could be other way round too)

so you can have

```
class Hand{ 
      string Id;
      bool Status;
      Pen pen = new Pen();
      Hand(string handId, String penId){
            id=handIdl;
            pen.id = penId;
            Status=false
      }
     setStatus(boolean status) {
       this.status = status;
       this.pen.status = status;
     }
}
class Pen{ 
      string Id
      bool Status;
      Pen(string id){
            Id=1;
            Status=false;
      }
}
```

You should Ideally have a similar structure, these are just pointers you need to take it further.

Hope it helps!

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for helping out it works for if i have 2 classes but sorry not to describe the question properly i have n number of classes with one main class like hand is main pen pencil eraser are different classes

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for not describing it earlier.